# what is the correct setup for hasura tables

Tags: variables, session, roles, hasura

user role permissions are not working. i am setting x-hasura-role to user but can't query a table where selection permission is allowed without any checks. also it is not possible to query from react apollo which was working before.

> hasura_session_variables

[image]

please see the permissions at the picture below :

> hasura_table_permissions

[image]

what is the possible misconfiguration here?

Comment: Can you click on `select` for user role and post all the permissions rules there?

Comment: all columns are selected if you are asking that. id, title and content.

Comment: Can you enable the header `x-hasura-admin-secret` in API Explorer? Since you have admin secret enabled, you can only make queries with arbitrary roles if you set the admin secret.

Comment: ah, ok, i got what you mean. i thought if admin checked the role is set to admin. now it works. thank you